# MacOS X Error when installing python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install python mysqldb in my mac but I got the following errors. For mysql I am using the one that is bundled with MAMP. Thanks!

here is the error message:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.darwin-8.11.1-i386-2.3/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.3/include/python2.3 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.darwin-8.11.1-i386-2.3/_mysql.o
_mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:76: error: parse error before 'MYSQL'
_mysql.c:76: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
_mysql.c:79: error: parse error before '}' token
_mysql.c:79: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of '_mysql_ConnectionObject'
_mysql.c:79: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's not enough to use the MySQL that's bundled with MAMP, as it does not contain the C development tools for MySQL (i.e. the header files such as `mysql.h`). [Here](http://www.mangoorange.com/2008/08/01/installing-python-mysqldb-122-on-mac-os-x/) is a step-by-step tutorial on compiling the MySQL extension for Python on Mac OS X, but it looks like you will need the "official" MySQL distribution for that.