# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb, mysql-python

I am running Trac 1.2.2 on Python 2.7 with MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have to move to Ubuntu 20.04 now. I know that Python 2.7 is not supported anymore, but I do still need to run it on my Ubuntu 20.04 server as I am running an older version of Trac which I can't upgrade right now because of plugins that are not working in the latest version...

So i migrated the MariaDB database, pip-installed MySQL-python with the help of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244866/mysqldb-install-error-mysql-c4423-error-my-config-h-no-such-file-or-dire/60828499#60828499) and I am now getting the following error in debugging-mode for Trac:

```
2021-03-18 10:16:31,836 Trac[main] ERROR: can't retrieve session: TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds. (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect')
```

Any idea of what I could have missed?

Comment: In this ticket https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/9916 the guy resolved (strangely) by fixing the file permissions.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but unfortunately, my tracenv is already owned by www-data :-/

Comment: @michael-ruth voilà ;-)

Comment: @Andreas, please post the code that produces this error. The error indicates that whatever calls the `connect()` method is actually a `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by my own. The file from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244866/mysqldb-install-error-mysql-c4423-error-my-config-h-no-such-file-or-dire/60828499#60828499) is not properly working under Ubuntu 20.04

I copied the file my_config.h from an Ubuntu 18.04 installation to my Ubuntu 20.04 into /usr/include/mysql and then did pip install MySQL-python again, and now everything works as it should :-)