# Unable to install MySQL-python - failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, mysql, config

Part of my project requires the MySQL-python package.
I'm running Linux Mint 20, kernel 5.11
I've had just about everything working fine up to this point. Just setup my virtual environment and all the packages install via poetry except MySQL-python. It fails with:

```
fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       44 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/matt/git/proj/test/python/.venv/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f_UUOG/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f_UUOG/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-XzgEIa/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/matt/git/proj/test/python/.venv/include/site/python2.7/mysql-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried adding a `my_config_h` folder to both `/usr/local/mysql and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26` (where it is automatically setup). Not sure how to get past this.

I have `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin` my bash config.
I tried linking/unlinking `mysql` with brew.
Did lots of googling and solutions that worked for others do not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: after solving a bunch of minor errors, the issue is now is this
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: cannot find -lzstd`
These are packages I believe inside both usr/bin and the above directory.

Here is more of the error output:

````
    /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: cannot find -lzstd
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1```
````

Comment: The `mysqlclient` pip package is a drop-in replacement. `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: This throws the following error:
```/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: cannot find -lzstd
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1```

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved with the following command: `sudo apt-get install libzstd-dev`

Answer (score 0):

With python 2.7 you can use

mysqlclient 1.3.5

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.5
```

MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.7, 3.3-3.4 are currently supported. PyPy is supported
use for example instead

But you shopuld urentyl update to python 3.8 ot 3.9

mysql-connector-python 8.0.26

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7 so the above distribution doesn't work

Comment: i there a good cause for using that putdqated Version of python?

Comment: @wheedwhackerjones  i added a version for python 2.7

Comment: When attempting to install mysqlclient==1.3.5 I get this error (basically same as original)
```fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1```

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61355803/5193536 and try to update to a newer python version

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pip package manager on your system, try the following:

```
pip3 install mysql-python
```

In case pip is not there, run these commands first

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I get the following errors when installing with the above command:
```ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql-python```
```print """You shouldn't be running this directly; it is used by setup.py."""
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("""You shouldn't be running this directly)?```
```raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required```
```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'```